# How do i access a fragment list declared in a layout file

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have declared a fragment(list fragment) in my layout file,'content_phone_book.xml' 
which corresponds to the activity PhoneBook :

the declaration of the fragment in the layout:

```
   <fragment
   android:id="@+id/mainActivityFrag"
   android:name="com.gilboa.dani.phonegate.MainListFragment"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Now, I want to access the fragment 'MainListFragment'(the one declared in the layout) from the containing PhoneBook activity so I could set the data inside the fragment. My question is, How can I access MainListFragment from the containing PhoneBook activity when the fragment is declared in the xml layout?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is get an instance of the fragment manager and then call `findFragmentById()`.

so something like this:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
Fragment mainFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById("mainActivityFrag");
```